# Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'. Available commands: kestrel

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, nginx, mono, dnx

Following [jsinh](https://stackoverflow.com/u/376196)'s [blog](http://blog.jsinh.in/hosting-asp-net-5-web-application-on-linux/),

I have created a web root directory for the ASP.NET project to reside using the below commands:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo mkdir /var/www/example.com
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/example.com
```

The domain name which I have used is literally [example.com](http://example.com)

Removed `default` file from below directories and restarted nginx using `sudo service nginx restart`

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/
/etc/nginx/sites-available/
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Added the below code to `project.json`:

```
{
"dependencies": {
  "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta6",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta6",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta6",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6"
},
"frameworks": {
   "dnx451": { },
 "dnxcore50": { },
},
"commands": {
  "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5004"
  }
}
```

Created `Startup.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
namespace HostKWebOnLinux
{
public class Startup
  {
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseWelcomePage();
    }
  }
}
```

executing `dnu restore` prints a lot of things on console, giving me an impression that packages are restored.

executing `dnx kestrel` results in:

> Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'. Available commands: kestrel.

I'm inside `var/www/example.com` and have tried both `dnx . kestrel` and `dnx kestrel`

This is how `var/www/example.com` looks like after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. There is no view file or nothing like that.

[image: var/www/example.com]

- How do I overcome this issue and run the project?

My final aim is to host ASP.NET on Ubuntu 14.4 using Nginx and Kestrel

Comment: Move to rc1. No one remembers what was broken in beta-6 - it is 3 releases old...

Comment: @Pawel My setup is quite [up to date](http://xameeramir.github.io/configure-net-ubuntu-linux/). I'm hesitant that this *could* be the issue.

Comment: packages and runtime should match. If your runtime is `rc1-final` your packages must be `rc1-final` as well and not `beta-6`

Comment: @Pawel Got it!! How do we see runtime version and packages version? I mean if there are any commands or so?

Comment: Dnvm list to show installed runtimes-the one that is currently active has star next to it.

Comment: @Pawel I'll try these and get back. It would be so great if we could host ASP.NET on Linux. Thanks for your inputs :)